# How to decrement / increment values based on value differences of the same group using postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table as below. Each `val1` and `val2` of same `no` have same value.

```
no    val1    val2
------------------
"1"   289.4   289
"1"   289.4   289
"1"   289.4   289
"1"   289.4   289
"2"   13.2    13.6
"2"   13.2    13.6
"2"   13.2    13.6
"2"   13.2    13.6
"3"   181     181.2
"3"   181     181.2
```

I want the table to be like below. The total of rows of same `no` always represent the difference in 0.1 scale. e.g : 4 rows of same `no`  = 0.4 difference, 3 rows of same `no`  = 0.3 difference.

If `val1` > `val2` of the same `no` :  decrement value by 0.1 using `val1` as upper bound and `val2` as lower bound, as below (`no` 1).
If `val1` < `val2` of the same  `no` : increment value by 0.1 using `val1` as lower bound and `val2` as upper bound, as below (`no` 2 and 3).

```
no    val1    val2
------------------
"1"   289.4   289.3
"1"   289.3   289.2
"1"   289.2   289.1
"1"   289.1   289
"2"   13.2    13.3
"2"   13.3    13.4
"2"   13.4    13.5
"2"   13.5    13.6
"3"   181     181.1
"3"   181.1   181.2
```

How to achieve this in postgresql? Thanks

Comment: What if you have 4 rows and 0.3 difference?

Comment: @Nick forgot to mention that, total of rows of same group always represent the difference in 0.1 scale. 4 rows = 0.4 difference, 3 rows = 0.3 difference.

Comment: OK. Is there another column that the rows are ordered by? e.g. `id`, or `timestamp`?

Comment: @Nick In my actual data there are other cols, but it doesn't matter. I only need to set the values based on `no` col

Comment: I understand that, the issue is deciding which of 4 what look to be identical rows to assign which set of numbers to e.g. which row gets `289.3 289.2` vs `289.4 289.3`

Comment: @Nick thanks for pointing that out. But for now my current table is ordered by the `no` col only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CTE` to assign row numbers to each set of values for a given `no` and compute the `diff` value to use for each row; then compute the new `val1` and `val2` values from the original `val1` value, the row number and the `diff`:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT no, val1,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY no ORDER BY NULL) AS rn,
         SIGN(val1 - val2) * 0.1 AS diff
  FROM data
)
SELECT no, 
       val1 - (rn - 1) * diff AS val1,
       val1 - rn * diff AS val2
FROM CTE
```

Output:

```
no      val1    val2
"1"     289.4   289.3
"1"     289.3   289.2
"1"     289.2   289.1
"1"     289.1   289
"2"     13.2    13.3
"2"     13.3    13.4
"2"     13.4    13.5
"2"     13.5    13.6
"3"     181     181.1
"3"     181.1   181.2
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e77e5/5)

Comment: wow the answer came faster than I expected and works fine. Very clever trick using `OVER` and `PARTITION` thank you!